# Retorno de Service

Tags: c#, ajax, .net, json

estou com o seguinte problema, eu faco uma chamada ajax para minha service e ela me retorna uma lista paginada tudo ok.. 
E tenho um botão onde faco o download para excel, só que por ser uma tabela bem pesada e não tenho como paginar isso no excel acabo tendo o erro de time out no retorno da minha chamada ajax.

Eu ouvi falar de uma parada que você faz a chamada e enquanto o serviço é processado tenho uma outra service perguntando se ele terminou e quando ele terminar retorna para o cliente, mas n tenho ideia do nome dessa chamada ou se existe alguma maneira melhor de realizar isso..

Alguém consegue me ajudar por favor ?

Comment: Tá falando de [Partial-Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206)?

Comment: Por que você não simplesmente serve o arquivo de excel sem ajax?

Comment: @Renan então eu tenho que fazer a chamada ajax pq minha UI não processa nada ela solicita tudo pra minha service entao eu preciso da ajax para realizar a chamada certo?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues se você é capaz de usar ajax, você é capaz de dar redirect pra URL do arquivo, o que é bem mais simples. Daí o navegador baixa o arquivo tranquilamente.

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias maneiras de implementar um mecanismo assim, chamado de *processo assíncrono*, onde o processamento de uma tarefa pesada ocorre em paralelo à requisição original. Um fluxo padrão poderia ser descrito da seguinte maneira:

- A tarefa `T1` é requisitada pelo cliente `C1`.
- O servidor inicializa uma *thread* em *background* onde a tarefa começa a ser executada. O mesmo atribui um ID a este processo - por exemplo, `ID1`.
- O servidor retorna o ID do processo para o cliente, permitindo que este continue a ser utilizado pelo usuário.
- De tempos em tempos o cliente pergunta, para o servidor, qual é o estado de execução da tarefa `ID1`; o retorno pode ser, por exemplo, 'cancelado', 'em execução' ou 'finalizado'.
- Se finalizado, o servidor pode retornar o conteúdo gerado pelo processamento em *background*.